# Based on user condition send emails in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a checkbox in dashboard.

> Case checked: then run a cron job.
>
> Case unchecked: dont run the cron job.

So the condition in controller:

```
if($checked){

  SendEmail::dispatch($users); 
}
```

My question is how should I go about this store the checkbox state on database or is there any other approach ?

Comment: so ? what's the problem with this approach ?

Comment: just wondering if someone has a better idea @Itisallyours

Comment: Need a bit more info really, otherwise you're going to get opinion based answers, which may not relate to your case at all. What is the end purpose? When should it run? If you've got multiple users clicking this box, should it run more than one? Is the setting personal to each user, or generic to the system?